# ExtJS REST store: sync() doesn't remove records on the server

Tags: json, rest, extjs, extjs4.2

I use ExtJS 4.2.2. A store for browsing and managing folders is defined like this:

```
Ext.define('hds.store.CaseFolders', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'app.model.Folder',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: false,
            model: 'app.model.Folder',
            storeId: 'Folders',
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: '/api/folders.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    messageProperty: 'message',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    writeAllFields: false,
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

It uses this model:

```
Ext.define('app.model.Folder', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'parentId',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'type',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]
});
```

Folders can be added, renamed and removed.

When changing the name of the folder, for example and using store.sync(), the record is properly synced to the server with a PUT containing id and name attributes.

However, when deleting the folder, store.sync() doesn't send any request to the server. A callback function was added to sync, but it is not called at all.

It seems that the REST store (proxy?) "thinks" that there is nothing to sync to the server.

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason for the problem that I had:

The store is filtered to show content of the folder to be deleted.

When wanting to delete current folder, its record is filtered away.

Adding a line to remove filters before removing the parent folder record solved the problem.